# How to configure code completion for Django based projects in PyDev?

Tags: django, pydev, code-completion

I am playing with a simple project based on Django framework. My IDE is PyDev/Eclipse.

I cannot make code completion work for Django code, but it works fine for standard Python libraries.
I tried to add Django dir (in my case C:\Program Files\Python26\Lib\site-packages\django) to PYTHONPATH both on PyDev level (Window->Preferences->PyDev->Interpreter - Python->libraries) and on a project level (Project->Properties->PyDev - PYTHONPATH) - no luck so far.

Can you please advise what I am missing here (preferably without installing PyDev extensions).

Comment: After I removed Django dir from system PYTHONPATH in PyDev it started to work. Apparently, If your django installed in site-packages, having C:\Program Files\Python26\Lib\site-packages\ in system PYTHONPATH is good enough (excuse my Windows accent). I tried to explicitly add another package (psycopg2) to system PYTHONPATH and got the same result - code completion stopped working for psycopg2. Interesting quirk of PyDev or am I missing some understanding of how PYTHONPATH works - why would it hurt to add those folders?

Comment: Well actually if you have already configured the interpreter in eclipse and then copy the psycopg2da folder to site-packages you have to add ...\lib\site-packages\psycopg2da manually as new folder to the "System PYTHONPATH" to get PyDev to see the new package

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I give it another try.

**Eclipse** in *C:\test\eclipse*

**Python 2.6.2** in *C:\test\python-2.6.2*

**Django 1.0.2 final** in *C:\test\python-2.6.2\Lib\site-packages* -> only the actual django folder not the docs, example, and so on. I did this without running setup.py as descriped in the INSTALL file.

Added *C:\test\python-2.6.2* and *C:\test\python-2.6.2\Lib\site-packages* to the **PATH** variable

As described [here](http://www.fabioz.com/pydev/manual_101_interpreter.html) I set the Interpreter in Eclipse by Window > preferences > pydev > Interpreter > Python. This automatically included a whole bunch of things under System libs like (C:\test\python-2.6.2\;C:\test\python-2.6.2\DLLs;C:\test\python-2.6.2\lib\site-packages;....). A whole bunch of Forced Builtins are also found.

Then I made a new "Pydev Project" added a package and there a new module with a class and a module which imports the class and calls a function from it. During writing this pressed Crtl+Space several times, and builtins as well as the new stuff from my Module where shown by code completion.

Comment: also, a hint how to make code completion work for your request parameters in the views.
1. Add from django.http import HttpRequest at the top of views.py
2. Add assert isinstance(request, HttpRequest) as the first code line of your view. Now you can enjoy code completion for request object. You can remove assert statement later.

based on this discussion:
http://www.mail-archive.com/pydev-users@lists.sourceforge.net/msg02595.html

Comment: PyDev can't typehint the HttpRequest *correctly*. Because Django's HttpRequest is filled with magic. For instance it can't find user property, it can't find FILES, GET, POST parameters. It fails to see encoding as a property, instead thinking it's a method. Sigh. Btw these days one can just do `":type request: HttpRequest"` to typehint, if the underlying class is not magic filled.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest [Configuring pydev to work with django](http://pydev.blogspot.com/2006/09/configuring-pydev-to-work-with-django.html) and

[Getting started Eclipse/Pyddev](http://fabioz.com/pydev/manual_101_root.html)

In the latter one there is a section specifically for code completion which mentions a problem with firewall or shell timeout. And in another section he mentions problems when (as in your case) the eclipse installations has spaces in the filepath

Comment: I've seen this post, it doesn't go into much details about configuring PYTHONPATH for Django

Answer (score 0):

I solved setting the PYTHONPATH too.
In the pallet Projects, right-click on the project -> properties
In the PYTHONPATH configuration you have to put the folder that contains your project as a external folder.

**Exemple:
/var/www/my_project
PYTHONPATH=/var/www/**